# How To Correctly Build libdatachannel For Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cross-compiling, libdatachannel

I've been trying to build [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel) for an **Android** project. I've tried both build options given:

- [POSIX-compliant operating systems](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/blob/master/BUILDING.md#posix-compliant-operating-systems-including-linux-and-apple-macos), and
- [Build directly with Make](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/blob/master/BUILDING.md#build-directly-with-make-linux-only).

I, however, keep getting the following error when I try to build the project in Android Studio C/C++:

```
ld: error: ../../../../libs/libdatachannel/libdatachannel.a(wstransport.o) is incompatible with aarch64linux.
```

Would you advise on how to get it working? How can I build it so that I get **ARM builds for Android**?

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer/related: https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/issues/595#issuecomment-1099111846 but details on your build environment: Linux/Mac, which host OS version, NDK version, etc. may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered [here](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel/discussions/742#discussioncomment-4144731)

It looks like libdatachannel is not built for the required ARM64 architecture. The easiest way to build it for the right target is to use the Android NDK toolchain file, something like:

```
$ cmake -B build -DUSE_GNUTLS=0 -DUSE_NICE=0 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[Path to the NDK]/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=[min SDK version]
```